# Mindtouch/Dekiwiki outputs strange URL (local://...)

Tags: apache-2.2, url, dekiwiki

I am currently testing a new Mindtouch installation on a Debian web server.

When using the Math-extension (a extension which uses LaTeX to convert mathematical formulas into .png images and shows them on the web-page), I simply receive no output from the math extension (not even an error message).

I was digging deeper into the problem, I noticed that the following HTML code is send from the server to the client where the image of the formula should be:

```
<img src="local://7c81b24bae6310e118b6b59b095eff15/deki/services/default/17/images/07adeb54-461a-d4c1-f66a-a69d14e29c2f.png" />
```

I have no idea what the problem could be here, since there are also no indications of any errors in the access, error or deki-api log. The error is also not reproducible on my local system with the same configuration steps done.

with best regards, emiswelt

**EDIT:**

As advised, I searched through the mindtouch forums, and woha, here is the solution: http://forums.developer.mindtouch.com/showthread.php?t=8112&highlight=math+local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local://... uri format is used by MindTouch's server for internal routing and generally should be translated to a public uri by the time it hits the wire. The fact that the Math extension is not properly translating the uri means that either the host or extension is misconfigured. I would suggest hitting up the [mindtouch forums](http://forums.developer.mindtouch.com/) with this issue, since troubleshooting is likely to require some more back and forth than what this Q&A format is meant for

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try this on monday, when I'm back at work. :).